# Build OpenSSL for Intel Xeon Phi on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, openssl, xeon-phi

I try build OpenSSl for Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor. 
So far as I understand this problem reduced to building OpenSSL for
"linux-generic64" as target ([this document](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/373907/intel-r-xeon-phi-tm-cluster-configuration_1.pdf)).

I have Windows10(x64) and VC2015.
So I use next string for configure:

`/perl ./Configure --prefix=D:\openssl\bin shared linux-generic64/`

```
nmake
```

But "nmake" command lead to failure. Here is a screen capture of the log:

[image]

Please, help me build OpenSSL for Intel Xeon Phi.

Best regards.

Comment: Building for linux-generic64 by launching VC++ through perl script on Windows seems to be pretty hard-core.

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does Microsoft tools support Xeon Phi? Can you find a MSDN document stating it? The Intel document you cited does not appear to discuss Microsoft or Visual Studio toolchains. You may need to switch to YASM and hack the [OpenSSL procedure on Windows](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.WIN).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I think I choose wrong way for solving my task. So I install a Linux on the Virtual Box and build the OpenSSL there. [This](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Building-OpenSSL-for-Intel-Xeon-Phi-td72922.html) is a link to my question on the OpenSSL forum